# Create a Rails app that can dynamically create new forms/database tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm a junior Rails developer who is creating a Rails app for a friend's business, and I hope someone out there can help answer my question!

My friend wants to be able to create new forms to gather information from her clients. She is not a programmer, and wants a simple interface, something easy to use like Google Forms. Ideally, the information gathered from these forms would be stored in the master database, so that if she loses a client, she wouldn't have to manually delete that client's entries in another database.

So I need to come up with a solution that:

- Doesn't force her to touch the code.
- Syncs with master database to automatically delete/nullify form entries when a client is dropped.

Does anybody know of elegant solutions for this type of problem?

Comment: Hire a skilled developer.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky, and liable to make your head spin a bit, when you come to make the form for building forms for example.  Surprisingly (from my googling at least) there doesn't seem to be a solution, eg a gem, already.

You'll need to think of all the different ways in which forms can differ, then build a schema to model that.  Something like

```
User
  has_many :form_templates

FormTemplate
  #columns: user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :form_template_fields, :order => "position"

FormTemplateField
  #columns: form_template_id, position, name, field_type

FormEntry
  #columns form_template_id, user_id
  belongs_to :form_template
  belongs_to :user


FieldEntry
  #columns: form_template_field_id, form_entry_id, data
  belongs_to :form_entry
  belongs_to :form_template_field
```

Now, when someone in **building** a form, they create a FormTemplate object and then create a collection of FormTemplateFields to sit in that form.

When someone completes the form, they will be creating a FormEntry record, linked to the FormTemplate and some FieldEntry records, each of which will be linked to one of the FormTemplateFields from that FormTemplate.

This is off the top of my head but might be a good starting point for thinking about it.